# Можно ли преобразовать дату в исходную строку из moment.js?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Есть строка вида `12 декабря 2018 г.`. Она получена с помощью moment.js из `2018-12-12 00:00:00+03`.

Можно ли теперь получить из преобразованной строки исходную?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const moment = require('moment');
moment.locale("ru");

const dateStr = '12 декабря 2018';
const date = moment(dateStr, 'DD MMMM YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ssZ');

console.log(date);  // выведет 2018-12-12 12:00:00+03:00
```